# How can I change InfoBox content?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this code :

```
var infoWindowOptions = {
    content: "content",

    ... some other options ...
};

var infowindow = new InfoBox(infoWindowOptions); 
infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

and it works without problems.
Now, I'd like to change content, so I've done :

```
infowindow.content = "new content";
infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

but it doesnt change! Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: infoBox and infowindow are two different things! which one are you referring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
infoWindow.setContent("new content");
```

DOM elements are also accepted.